# Where should I place manifest.json in my Laravel 5.3 project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gulp, laravel-5.3, progressive-web-apps

Where should I place the `manifest.json` file in my Laravel 5.3 application?

Or how can I check if it's working?

Specifically, I'm willing to know whether it goes under `public/` straight away or `resources/assets` and wire up anything with *Gulp*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how are you going to use the `manifest.json`, if you are calling this file via server side (PHP), you can put this in `resources/assets`.

But if are calling this file via client side (javascript or something) or you want anyone to access this file publicly, you can put this in `public/`